# NSString NSArray to Joined String with "and" Between Last Two Items

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have an `NSArray` of String phrases like @`[@"unanswered questions", @"inspection purpose not selected", @"customer name empty"]`.

I would like to combine these strings in to a comma separated string with the word `@"and"` coming between the last two items.

`NSArray` `componentsJoinedByString` will join with commas, but won't put in the `@" and "`.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"unanswered questions", @"inspection purpose not selected", @"customer name empty"];
NSString *str = array[0];

if (array.count > 1)
    for (int i=1; i<array.count-1 ;i++) {
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",str,array[i]];
    }
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ and %@",str,array.lastObject];
}

NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Comment: This definitely works! THANKS! I wish it didn't create so many string objects. Feels a little memory wasteful but that's the bane of immutability.

Comment: because it should append into a mutable string.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing.

```
+ (NSString*)joinStringArrayWithAnd:(NSArray*)strings
{
    if (strings.count > 1) {
        NSMutableArray *mutableStrings = [strings mutableCopy];
        mutableStrings[strings.count - 1] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"and %@", strings[strings.count - 1]];
        strings = mutableStrings;
    }
    return [strings componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you set `strings = mutableStrings` in your `if`?

Answer (score 0):

Call `componentsJoinedByString` to get your comma separated strings, then string-replace the *last* comma with `@" and "`

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I ended up adding an "and " to the last item which is very similar to what you suggested.

Comment: Nice solution, it's the shortest one here clocking in at only two lines. However, this approach will fail if your last string contains commas for some crazy reason!

Comment: I was thinking about that too, but that's a different problem, right? The comma delimiting fails because you already have commas.

Answer (score 0):

A more flexible solution would be to iterate over each NSString in your array and append it to the final string:

```
NSString *finalString = @"";

//Iterate over the strings from your array
for (int i=0; i<[yourArray count]; i++) {

    if(i != yourArray.count-1)
        finalString = [finalString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, ", yourArray[i]]];
    else
        finalString = [finalString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"and %@", yourArray[i]]];

}
```

Comment: I like this option, but if the length of strings is only 1, it would put an and in front of just the one item.

Comment: Correct. You can check the array count before iterating, though.

Comment: You should set your `finalString = yourArray[0]` and then proceed from 1, otherwise you will start with a comma.

Comment: Actually the format of the string is "%@, " , so it would not start with a comma. But yes, that's an alternative.

Comment: @Sebyddd Oh right, you will have a `, and` there. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Here's davide rosetto's answer but using a mutable string:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"unanswered questions", @"inspection purpose not selected", @"customer name empty"];
NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:array[0]];

if (array.count > 1) {
    for (int i = 1; i < array.count - 1; i++) {
        [str appendFormat:@", %@", array[i]];
    }
    [str appendFormat:@" and %@", array.lastObject];
}
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Answer (score -1):

Is the count of items in the array always fixed? If so, you could do it with something like:

NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@, %@ and %@", phrases[0], phrases[1], phrases[2]];

-ken

Comment: The length is not always the same and sometimes it could be one item.